Issues with hook in Typo3 v11/v12 custom extension when child record needs to be deleted
I have an issue with my custom hook. I created a new hook and declare it in ext_localconf.php file. When I perform action to delete file from the filelist,  I need to call in my hook method processCmdmap_deleteAction(). It doesn't work now, because my file has been deleted without perform my method where I want to delete my other records. I'm sure this issue is related with this method processCmdmap_deleteAction and my hook (db table and structure is configured properly).
Do you have any idea, why Typo3 can't run my custom hook and mentioned method when I delete record from the filelist page in the backend side of Typo3 instance?
Body of my hook class:
public function processCmdmap_deleteAction(string $table, int $recordId): void
{
    if ('sys_file_metadata' === $table) {
        $this->deleteRelatedChildren($recordId);
    }
}

/**
 * Delete related child records based on parent ID.
 */
public function deleteRelatedChildren(int $parentId): void
{
    $connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable('tx_extensionName_domain_model_alternative_history');

    $queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder
        ->delete('tx_extensionName_domain_model_alternative_history')
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('sys_file_metadata', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($parentId, \PDO::PARAM_INT))
        );

    $queryBuilder->execute();
}

What I did:

check ext_localconf.php configuration


$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass']['extensionName'] = extensionName\Backend\Hooks\MyCustomHook::class;


check method processCmdmap_deleteAction in default hook of Typo3 instance (in my opinion I should use this method to delete my records, when I delete file)
another hook methods works properly (for example I use methodprocessDatamap_postProcessFieldArray to update my records in my custom table in db)
check documentation and another threads in stack to get some more information how to solve this issue, but without effect
ask ChatGPT to get some tips, but without effect too
search some tips in the web, but I didn't found solution

Greetings, Chanyss921

You should not implement new hooks anymore. Instead use PSR-14 Events dispatching. But nevertheless. Please show how your hook is implemented in your custom extension.

Hello again. :)
I updated primary post with my code in hook.

The implementation in ext_localconf.php looks ok.
Please check if your hook is called at all. If you do not use a debugger ie. XDebug, you could test it with a simple die():
public function processCmdmap_deleteAction(string $table, int $recordId): void
{
    die('Is called');
    if ('sys_file_metadata' === $table) {
        $this->deleteRelatedChildren($recordId);
    }
}

If it's not called, then try to implement it as follows in your ext_localconf.php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass'][]
    = extensionName\Backend\Hooks\MyCustomHook::class;

Just making sure that you do not try to register two custom HookClasses for same extensionname.
And then please check how the deleteAction is implemented by i.e. workspaces:
https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/workspaces/blob/b9c22190e0d3698239048ec08b0b2ab02cb093d4/Classes/Hook/DataHandlerHook.php#L204
Your method seems to be missing some parameters.

Thank you for the answer.
Yes, I checked it earlier with xdebug and hook isn't called...
I have registered in ext_localconf.php two $GLOBALS for my hook.
For testing purposes I deleted first registration of 'processDatamapClass', after that I cleared cache and result is the same. Moreover I tried to pass my hook into similar array [] without 'extensionName' and still doesn't work.
This first declaration works fine, I have issue only with 'processCmdmapClass' method in this custom hook.
This is my declaration of hook in ext_localconf.php (as I wrote earlier for testing purposes I deleted first declaration 'processDatamapClass'):
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass']['extensionName'] = extensionName\Backend\Hooks\CustomHook::class; $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass']['extensionName'] = extensionName\Backend\Hooks\CustomHook::class;
Yes, I know about missing parameters, but I was forced to remove them, because they aren't used (phpstan and phpmd tests threw me errors..., I will revert these changes to be 100% sure that's not the case).
Greetings, Chanyss921
EDIT:
I found a solution - I created a new event and connected it to an event called BeforeFileDeletedEvent.
Now it works properly, thank you again for help Mogens and have a nice week.
Greetings, Chanyss921
